# Adding nodes to Cassandra Cluster

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have a 1 node - 1 cluster Cassandra running on my local machine. I want to see how Cassandra scales up, when I simply add the second node to the same cluster. The second node that I am adding will also run from my local machine.

I have been trying to lookup a lot of approaches to do this, but can't find any. Any simple way through which I can add second instance of Cassandra to my cluster?

Comment: Maybe the easiest (slow, though) would be to have a VPS that has a shared IP address so you can connect to/from it. I have done that to test with many nodes, but the hard drives are just really slow when you have too many in this way.

Answer (score 8):

The act of adding a second node is known as bootstrapping. The procedure is straightforward:

- Make sure the cluster names match in cassandra.yaml
- Point the new (joining) node to the cluster using the seeds setting in the yaml
- Start cassandra, it will join.

[This is described in detail online](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_add_node_to_cluster_t.html), but one of the easiest ways to see it in action is using [ccm](https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm) , which is a tool many cassandra developers use to setup fake clusters on their local computers.

Currently (all versions up to 3.9), Cassandra's unique ID is an IP - you can only have one instance per IP. If you need more than one cassandra instance per computer, you need to use multiple IPs.

Comment: It is "straightforward" when you use one computer per node.

Comment: so, there´s nothing that I´ve to do in the old node?

Comment: You should run "nodetool cleanup" on the old node after the new node has finished joining (shows UP/NORMAL in the ring). That will remove the data that was previously owned, but is no longer owned by that instance.